# numpy - why np.multiply.reduce([], axis=None) results in 1?

Tags: numpy

Why multiply & reduce non-existing element in an empty array-like results in 1?

```
np.multiply.reduce([], axis=None)
---
1
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product

Comment: ```np.multiply.identity = 1```

Comment: What's the alternative?  Error?  0?

Comment: @hpaulj, I was expecting Error or None but not sure how to understand the meaning of "multiply empty" which results in 1.

Comment: See also: `np.sum([])` returns 0.0.

Comment: `reduce` starts with something, and repeatedly applies the operation.  The iniial value is chosen to make sense.  For example 0 would be bad for multiply, but good for add.

Comment: More on the `initial` parameter on the `reduce` page https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ufunc` may have an `identify` attribute:

```
In [200]: np.multiply.identity
Out[200]: 1
In [201]: np.multiply.reduce([])
Out[201]: 1.0
```

which can be replaced in a `reduce`:

```
In [202]: np.multiply.reduce([], initial=10)
Out[202]: 10.0
In [203]: np.multiply.reduce([1,2,3], initial=10)
Out[203]: 60
In [204]: np.multiply.reduce([1,2,3], initial=None)
Out[204]: 6
```

and if `None`,it can produce an error:

```
In [205]: np.multiply.reduce([], initial=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-205-1c3b1c890fd6>", line 1, in <module>
    np.multiply.reduce([], initial=None)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation multiply which has no identity
```

`max` is a ufunc without an intial:

```
In [211]: np.max([])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-211-93f3814168a1>", line 1, in <module>
    np.max([])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in amax
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2733, in amax
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.maximum, 'max', axis, None, out,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 87, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

In [212]: np.max([], initial=-1)
Out[212]: -1.0
```

### Python `reduce`

```
In [222]: from functools import reduce
In [223]: reduce?
Docstring:
reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value

Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).  If initial is present, it is placed before the items
of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
sequence is empty.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

So with a multiply lambda:

```
In [224]: reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,[1,2,3])
Out[224]: 6
```

For a empty list, error is the default behavior:

```
In [225]: reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,[])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-225-780706778563>", line 1, in <module>
    reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,[])
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

But with a supplied initial value:

```
In [227]: reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,[],1)
Out[227]: 1
```